# Finding and deleting related nodes not related to other nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In our application (java 8) we use NEO4J (3.4) and for a feature we need a query that does the following:

Remove all nodes of type 'Team' that do not have a relationship 'OWNS' and all related nodes of type 'Employee' with the relationship 'MEMBER_OF' to 'Team' but only if there are not other Employee relationships to other Team nodes.

I'm quite new to NEO4J version 3.4 and have some basic knowledge of the Cypher language but this one is for now beyond me.

The first part of the query i get:

```
MATCH (team:Team) WHERE NOT (team)-[:OWNS]->() RETURN team
```

and i could start iterating over the result set, etc.. but i bet there is a query for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (team:Team) WHERE NOT (team)-[:OWNS]->()
OPTIONAL MATCH (team)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(emp:Employee)
WITH team, CASE
  WHEN emp IS NULL THEN []
  ELSE COLLECT({emp: emp, cnt: SIZE([(emp)--(t2:Team) WHERE team<>t2|t2])}) END AS data
DETACH DELETE team
FOREACH(e IN [d IN data WHERE d.cnt = 0 | d.emp] | DETACH DELETE e)
```

[UPDATED 2]

And here is an improved version of your own answer. It is more explicit about node labels and relationship types, and only attempts to delete the `team` once.

```
MATCH (team:Team) WHERE NOT (team)-[:OWNS]->()
OPTIONAL MATCH (team)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(emp:Employee)
WHERE SIZE((emp)--(:Team)) = 1
WITH COLLECT(emp) + team AS del
FOREACH(x IN del | DETACH DELETE x)
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me in solving the problem. I did however simplified it and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using

```
MATCH (team:Team) WHERE NOT (team)-[:OWNS]->()
WITH team
OPTIONAL MATCH (team)-[r]-(allRelatedNodes)
WHERE size((allRelatedNodes)--()) = 1
DETACH DELETE team, allRelatedNodes
```

do need to test is with more data but it seems to work

Comment: This query is fragile and depends on you never adding node labels or relationship types to the DB. And it tries to delete the same team multiple times. See the update to my answer for a form of your query that should be safer.

Comment: thanks, much more efficient indeed! For our use case we do a 'repopulation' of the database everytime.